# KeyDown event is triggered only when the page contains a button

Tags: windows-runtime

I have a page with a KeyDown handler, but I noticed that the handler is not invoked if the page does not contain a button.

E.g., the handler is not invoked in this case:

```
<Page
...
KeyDown="Page_KeyDown">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

But it is invoked in this case:

```
<Page
...
KeyDown="Page_KeyDown">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock />
        <Button>xxxxx</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Any idea why does this happen? Can I make the KeyDown event work even without a button?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortucts in Metro apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750963/keyboard-shortucts-in-metro-apps)